# Java Installer Generator for eclipse (plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I'm looking for an eclipse plugin (free or commercial) installer generator, something similar to [IzPack](http://izpack.org/), but integrated into eclipse(plugin). Does it exist some plugin to generate application installer ?

Possibly cross-platform.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  I don't understand why somebody would want an installer generator for eclipse, after all, all you would be giving the final user would be an executable JAR.

Comment: An eclipse plugin like IzPack, this is useful to create auto installable package for costumer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS is a good language for creating exe's. I use [EclipseNSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EclipseNSIS_-_NSIS_plugin_for_Eclipse). It's a great plugin that has a built in wizard. From the NSIS language you will get a working exe.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you [Java Executable Wrapper Plugin for Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_Executable_Wrapper_Plugin_for_Eclipse)
[link2](http://code.google.com/p/google-summer-of-code-2007-eclipse/downloads/detail?name=Zhang_Rui.tar.gz&can=2&q=)

You can also convert executable jar to exe. See [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=525).